# using django smart_selectors with django_cities_light not working

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using django **cities_light**, but what I want is: Region drop down to be depend on Country and city drop down on region.

for achieving this I installed **smart_selectors** to flirter them using **ChainedForeignKey** and The Strange thing is, it worked for the first time but when I checked it other day it wont wrok anymore.

this is the code I am using

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey
from cities_light.models import Country, City, Region

    
    Class Address(Models.Model):
        
    #i tried this before did not work
    #country = models.ForeignKey('cities_light.Country', #on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,         #blank=True)
    
        # Country, City and State
        country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        
    
        region = ChainedForeignKey(
            Region,
            chained_field="country",
            chained_model_field="country",
            show_all=False,
            auto_choose=True,
            null=True
        )
    
        city = ChainedForeignKey(
            City,
            chained_field="state",
            chained_model_field="region",
            show_all=False,
            auto_choose=True,
            null=True
        )
```

[I am attaching screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoNA0.png)

and they dont get chained somehow I dont know what I am doing wrong

I was expeting them to chained and fliter regions and then cities xD

and I get this in terminal Log

"GET /chaining/filter/cities_light/Region/country/Contacts/Address/region/8/ HTTP/1.1" 404 6160